# Error while using Wand with Flask on Ubuntu

Tags: python, flask, imagemagick, wand

When I call the following code from my flask application I receive an error of varying numbers with the following code more or less.  The only issue is when I ssh into my server and activate the same virtual environment and run the same code it works flawlessly.

I can't quite wrap my head around what is going on.  Whether there is a setting in my uwsgi file that points away from where wand is imported.  If anyone has face this problem I would love the help debugging it.

> wand contains no images `MagickWand-1' @ error/magick-image.c/MagickWriteImage

```
from wand.image import Image
p = 'path-to-pdf-document-page0'
with Image(filename=p) as img:
    img.save(filename="path-to-save-image")
```

Comment: Double check ghostscript is installed, and usable by the flask environment. PDF conversions can fail silently if ghostscipt doesn't return correctly.

Comment: @emcconville Its definitely installed.  not sure about how to tell if its usable though